# Como pasar parametros con react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, componentes

tengo definidas unas rutas con un layout

```
 function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>

            <Route index element={<Inicio />} />
            <Route path="ventas" element={<Ventas />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

COmo le paso parametros del componente Inicio hacia layout y recibir los parametros en el layout

```
export const Inicio = () => {  
  return (
      <div>
        Inicio
      </div>
  )
}
```

Desde el componente inicio quiero pasarle parametros al layout

Comment: Bienvenid@ a la comunidad, ¿Que versión del router estas usando?

Comment: version es 18.2.0